# How to resolve a 'undefined proptype' error with react, redux and graphql

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, use-effect

I am trying to learn how to build a React/Redux app with graphql but I am having an issue resolving the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'record' of undefined' error.

I am getting this error specifically when I am trying to pull the 'record' ID from the url (.../record/:recordId) using 'match.params.recordId' and send it to the action/reducer methods.

My code includes console.log statements to try to track the value of the 'record' prop between the component, action and reducer however the logs are never called. This leads me to believe the component never uses the 'useEffect' hook to call the action but I am unsure.

MyRecord Component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { getrecord } from '../../actions/records';
import { Container, Row, Col, Card, Button, Form, ListGroup, Jumbotron, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';



const MyRecord = ({getrecord, match, recordID = {id: match.params.recordId}, thisRecord:{record, loading}}) => {
    useEffect(() => {  
        getrecord(recordID);
    }, [getrecord, recordID]);

    const LogInfo = () =>{
        console.log('record ID: ',match.params.id);
        console.log('record: ', record);
    }
    
    LogInfo();
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <>
            {record === null ? (
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : (
            <Container id='MyRecord'>
                <Row>
                <Jumbotron className='recordJumbotron'>
                    <h1>Record: {record.recordname} </h1>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                                Add an Item To Your Record
                            </Button>
                            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                                <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                                </Modal.Header>
                                <Modal.Body>
                                <Form>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                                        <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                                        </Form.Text>
                                    </Form.Group>

                                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                                        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                                        Submit
                                    </Button>
                                </Form>
                                </Modal.Body>
                                <Modal.Footer>
                                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                                    Save Changes
                                </Button>
                                </Modal.Footer>
                            </Modal>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Button>Upload a Document</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Jumbotron>
                </Row>

                <Row className='recordItemList'>
                <Card className='recordItemList'>
                    <Card.Header>Record Items</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>Special title treatment</Card.Title>
                        <ListGroup variant="flush">
                            <ListGroup.Item>Cras justo odio</ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>Dapibus ac facilisis in</ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>Morbi leo risus</ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>Porta ac consectetur ac</ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </Row>
            </Container>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

MyRecord.propTypes = {
    getrecord: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    thisRecord: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   thisRecord: state.record
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getrecord})(MyRecord)
```

Records Reducer File:

```
import {
    CREATE_RECORD_SUCCESS,
    CREATE_RECORD_FAIL,
    LIST_RECORDS_BY_OWNER,
    GET_RECORD_BY_OWNER,
    GET_RECORDS_SUBSCRIPTION
  } from '../actions/types';

  const initialState = {
    record: null,
    records: [],
    loading: true,
    error: {}
  };

  export default function (state = initialState, action) {
      const {type, payload} = action;

      switch(type){
        
        case CREATE_RECORD_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                //record:[payload, ...state.records],
                loading: false
            };
        case GET_RECORD_BY_OWNER:
            return {
                ...state,              
                record: payload,
                loading: false
            };
        
        case LIST_RECORDS_BY_OWNER:
            return {
                ...state,              
                records:payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case GET_RECORDS_SUBSCRIPTION:
            return {
                ...state,              
                records:[payload, ...state.records],
                loading: false
            };
        case CREATE_RECORD_FAIL:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: payload,
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
        }
}
```

Records Action:

```
//GET A RECORD
//GET A RECORD
export const getrecord = (recordID) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        console.log(' id: ', recordID);
        const res = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getRecord, recordID)) 
        console.log('record by id: ', res.data.getRecord);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_RECORD_BY_OWNER,
            payload: res.data.getRecord
        })
        console.log('getrecord: ', res)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        dispatch({
            type: CREATE_RECORD_FAIL         
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong import for Proptype. this would be

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

and validation would be:

```
MyRecord.propTypes = {
    getrecord: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    thisRecord: PropTypes.object
};
```

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo, the code has been updated. Unfortunately this is not helping with the undefined prop...

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate when using object operational chain

Check undefined before using it

`match?.params?.recordId`

In this way, it's will prevent error.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The issue was in fact in my component. My mapStateToProps method had the typo '...state.record' but should have been '...state.records' due to the action set name. This is why 'record' was undefined and the action/record methods were never even getting invoked.